# Send Email from oracle trigger - if any DML happens

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have a table called TEST_TABLE. I need to get an email alert, if any changes happened in this table (like insert,update,delete & drop).

I think by using DB trigger, we can get the alert.

so can anyone please help me how to write the oracle trigger with this changes?

Comment: Please show some research or code you have tried.

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=emailing-after-inserting-into-database-tables This may help

Comment: DROP is a system event not a DML command.

Comment: What you're looking for is the Oracle built-in package UTL_MAIL. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_MAIL.html#GUID-47AE34E9-3123-4115-AC86-4FF538DBFBBB)

Answer (score 2):

Actually i would question this requirement,

Triggers are a bad way to do "non-transactional" things such as sending mail, or creating "text" file, reason is that in the event you have an exception in your transaction statement the trigger would have fired already.

begin
insert into table select 1/0,'Hello i am new';
-- The trigger fires and sends mail, thought he insert failed.
commit;/*-- we never reach here..*/
end;

The alternative you have is to create a dbms_job and have the trigger call this job in the trigger body.

The difference: dbms_job gets submitted only if there is a successful commit.

See an excellent discussion on ask tom on this

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=email-in-plsql